# How to "fix" a range so that copy/paste doesn't increment it

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

When filling [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114675/24327) formula down a column:

`=if(OR(H5>=LARGE(UNIQUE(H1:H11),1), H5>=LARGE(UNIQUE(H1:H11),2)), "top", "")`

When I copy/paste it from row 5 to row 6 I get:

`=if(OR(H6>=LARGE(UNIQUE(H2:H12),1), H6>=LARGE(UNIQUE(H2:H12),2)), "top", "")`

`H6` is correct, but, for range `H2:H12` should stay as `H1:H11`.  The copy/paste is anticipating and changing the formula.  Normally that works fine.

How can I alter the formula, or alter the copy/paste process, so that the comparison range is fixed?

Or, perhaps, define the comparison range somehow?  The caveat being that I don't want delve too deeply into formulas.  Not so much for the KISS principle but in consideration of the learning curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use $ sign to lock range.

```
$H$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lock the range it should be like this

=IF(OR(H5>=LARGE(UNIQUE($H$1:$H$11),1), H5>=LARGE(UNIQUE($H$1:$H$11),2)), "top", "")